# Conda fails to install flask-bootstrap

Tags: python-3.x, flask, conda, miniconda, flask-bootstrap

Conda refuses to carry out conda install flask-bootstrap. I have miniconda. Restarting my computer didn't help. I don't really know what else is pertinent but ill be around to respond if more info is needed. I don't know what else to say here bbut stackexchange needs me to add some more details so here.

Ive tried updating conda and degrading conda to 4.6.11. I tried it on my base environment and it doesnt seem to work there either.

My packages:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alembic                   1.0.11                     py_0  
amqp                      2.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1  
billiard                  3.6.0.0          py37h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                      py37_0  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0  
celery                    4.4.0rc1                   py_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1  
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
conda                     4.6.11                   py37_0  
conda-package-handling    1.3.11                   py37_0  
cryptography              2.7              py37ha12b0ac_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
flask-login               0.4.1                    py37_0  
flask-mail                0.9.1                      py_2    conda-forge
flask-migrate             2.4.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
flask-sqlalchemy          2.4.0                      py_0  
flask-wtf                 0.14.2                   py37_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10.1                   py37_0  
kombu                     4.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
mako                      1.0.10                     py_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
openssl                   1.1.1c               h1de35cc_1  
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py37_0  
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0  
pyperclip                 1.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.3                h359304d_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-editor             1.0.4                      py_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_11  
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
redis                     5.0.3                h1de35cc_0  
redis-py                  3.2.1                      py_0  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h1de35cc_0  
selenium                  3.141.0          py37h1de35cc_0  
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0  
simplejson                3.16.0           py37h1de35cc_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.8                      py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.5            py37h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.29.0               ha441bb4_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
tqdm                      4.32.1                     py_0  
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0  
vine                      1.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0  
wtforms                   2.2.1                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

Error message:

```
conda install flask-bootstrap
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Initial quick solve with frozen env failed.  Unfreezing env and trying again.
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Initial quick solve with frozen env failed.  Unfreezing env and trying again.
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

  - flask-bootstrap -> python[version='2.7.*,3.5.*,>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to.  Your current python version
is (python=3.7).  Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version
unless you explicitly specify that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package setuptools conflicts for:
flask-bootstrap -> flask[version='>=0.8'] -> jinja2[version='>=2.10,>=2.4'] -> setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools
Package wheel conflicts for:
flask-bootstrap -> flask[version='>=0.8'] -> jinja2[version='>=2.10,>=2.4'] -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09'] -> python[version='2.7.*,3.5.*,>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
Package certifi conflicts for:
flask-bootstrap -> flask[version='>=0.8'] -> jinja2[version='>=2.10,>=2.4'] -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
Package pip conflicts for:
flask-bootstrap -> flask[version='>=0.8'] -> jinja2[version='>=2.10,>=2.4'] -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09'] -> python[version='2.7.*,3.5.*,>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
python=3.7 -> pip
```

Comment: Can you edit the output of `conda config --show channels` into your question?

Comment: As a workaround, you can try: `conda install -c conda-forge --override-channels flask-bootstrap`

Comment: I think the issue is that flask-bootstrap only works with python 3.5. Do you know what I can do about it short of creating a new env? (I used a lot of fstrings in my code which dont work in 3.5)